# Does the digital will need to be separate from the regular will?

Tags: united-states, wills

Do I need to maintain two separate wills, one for my digital life (accounts, passwords, etc.) and one for my regular life (assets), or I can I bake my digital will into my regular will?

Comment: From an IT security POV, writting a password anywhere that is not under your control is a security risk. Also, there is the problem of keeping the password updated. I would say that a more appropiate way of doing this (again, from an IT POV) is to just detail the instructions ("X can handle my Facebook account, Y can handle my gmail account") so that proper documents are sent to the service providers so they proceed to reset the passwords and give the new one to the "heir".

Comment: @SJuan76 Interesting idea. I didn't know I could get away with not writing down my actual passwords in the will. That's good to know

Comment: @pushkin Not only that, but the terms of service of some of your accounts (like a bank account) may very well prohibit sharing your login information with anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, but probably shouldn't.

A better approach would be, for example, to leave someone "the contents of my safe deposit box at XYZ bank" or "the contents of my office desk drawers" and the right to use any intangible property whose access codes are contained therein.